# Using machine learning how do we determine if a given description about activity is under corporate social responsibility or not?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, text-mining

Given a description:

for example:

"I'm a proactive member of the XYZ On Demand Community (ODC). This platform helps us to engage with community organizations and expand the value of our volunteering efforts."

is a csr description just by reading as the social activity is related to some contribution through company initiatives.

How do we predict this using a machine learning model.

The model should be able to classify it as csr description or non - csr.